# python ctypes to access system.dll classes

Tags: python, ctypes

How can I access system.dll classes using ctypes?

```
from ctypes import *

lib_sys = CDLL(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll")

_impersonatedUser = lib_sys.security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext  # <-- exception: "function 'security' not found."
```

This gives the error message `function 'security' not found.` when trying to use the class.

I'm using Python 2.7 (64 bit).

Need a native python solution.

Comment: It's "C"types, not "C#" or "C++"types.

Comment: As @MarkTolonen said, you can't call C# or C++ shared libraries with ctypes. That being said, the [ironPython](https://ironpython.net/) interpreter can call .Net methods.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have code in VB.Net that does user impersonation. I'm trying to accomplish the same thing using native python.

Comment: Check out [Python.NET](http://pythonnet.github.io/).  It allows calling the CLR from native CPython.